# how to image view right of from image view center horisontal

Tags: android-layout

i want my android layout [image: this]
but i difficult to layout image [image: this]

i was tried to drawable dashed :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorwhite"
    android:dashWidth="60px"
    android:dashGap="30px"
    android:width="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

but when i layouting in xml text :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/verifikasiemail"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stripstrip"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my result

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change  android:layout_width="0dp" of second image.